# When authenticating a user, can I send the first jwt back in the header, and the relevant data in the body?

Tags: spring, jwt

My setup is :

- POST username and password to /authenticate endpoint
- Spring security validates the credentials, and creates a JWT with the username as the subject and sends it to the client.

So now I'm setting up the client and I want to know if there's some problem with either attaching the JWT as a field in the response body, or putting the JWT in the header, along with the response body.

Because without doing one of those things, now the client has to send a second request (now I know I can put the JWT in the header, Authorization: Bearer ...), Spring decrypts the JWT and then sends a new response with the User data.

Is it convention to send the authorization response with the JWT only, no user data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say it is ok to return some user data upon authentication in addition to the JWT token.
With the JWT token the consumer could then retrieve the user data, so why not saving a roundtrip to the server?